# Is there any method to get the address of the result?

Tags: google-sheets

When I use the filter or query to get the result, I want to get the address of the result.

The result is a string type, But `column()` or `row()` methods just accept the range on the parameter.

Is there any method to get the address?

Such like the original function `address(1,2,4)` result (B1)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I add the picture after that.
Hope can make the question more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=CELL("address", INDEX(A2:A, MATCH(
 FILTER(A2:A, A2:A="Nancy"),
 A2:A, 0), 1))
```

[image]

### _______________________________________________________________

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CELL("address", INDEX(A2:A, MATCH(
 FILTER(A2:A, A2:A="Nancy"),
 A2:A, 0), 1)), "\$", "")
```

[image]